# Azure Mounted File Storage is not a valid Virtual Path

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, file-storage

I have an Azure Mounted file storage in my App Service for storing files.

Path is c:/mountedstorage/appfiles

Im trying to get FileInfo for each file I pull down so I can give the user a download time and show the size of the download.

```
if (listItem.ToLower().Contains("htmlModules"))
{
    var path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~" + listItem);
    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        var fi = new FileInfo(path);
        length += fi.Length;
    }
}
```

Issue is that I get the virtual path error like so:
~C:/mountedstorage/appfiles/htmlModules/31822417-dee3-4eab-abdf-fb922d59ccad/runmovie.html' is not a valid virtual path.

Does anyone know how i can get the FileInfo for a file stored on a mounted file share?

Comment: The error you're encountering is due to the incorrect usage of Server.MapPath for a physical path. Server.MapPath is designed to map a virtual path, relative to the server's application root, to a physical file path on the server. Since c:/mountedstorage/appfiles is already a physical path, there's no need to use Server.MapPath. To handle files on a mounted Azure file storage, you should directly use the physical file path.